# project with localisation folder and classes?

Tags: c#, silverlight, resources

I'm trying to use a new resources file with localisation in a Silverlight Project from 2009.

I've added a new resource file to the folder Resources in my Silverlight Application and if

I try to use the new resources in a control (.xaml) I get the blue underlining with the message "could not resolve resTest.resx).

I found a folder "Localisation" with classes like this:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication.Localization{
public class ContentGrid
{
    public ContentGrid() { 

    }

    private static Resources.ContentGrid _Resource = new SilverlightApplication.Resources.ContentGrid();

    public Resources.ContentGrid Resource
    {
        get
        {
            return _Resource;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I've added a new class for my new resources file, but it doesn't work. Still the same error. I only know the automatic resources method, where I put a resource file in the folder Resources and everything works automatic.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the flowing article which explains how to make xaml content localizable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882554%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

I forgot to make an entry in the app.xaml file.